# Remove Duplicates and show Total sales by year and month

Tags: sql

i am trying to work with this query to produce a list of all 11 years and 12 months within the years with the sales data for each month. Any suggestions? this is my query so far.

```
SELECT 
     distinct(extract(year from date)) as year
     , sum(sale_dollars) as year_sales
from `project-1-349215.Dataset.sales`
group by date
```

it just creates a long list of over 2000 results when i am expecting 132 max one for each month in the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your group by statement if you have more results than you expected.

You can try:

```sql
group by YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

or

```sql
group by EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date)
```

Answer (score 1):

A Grouping function is for takes a subsection of the date in your case year and moth and collect all rows that fit, and sum it up,

So a s´GROUp BY date makes no sense, what so ever as you don't want the sum of every day

So make this

```
SELECT 
     extract(year from date) as year
     ,extract(MONTH from date) as month
     , sum(sale_dollars) as year_sales
from `project-1-349215.Dataset.sales`
group by 1,2
```

Or you can combine both year and month

```
SELECT 
     extract(YEAR_MONTH from date) as year
     , sum(sale_dollars) as year_sales
from `project-1-349215.Dataset.sales`
group by 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! What does the 1, 2 in the function represent?

Comment: The group by 1,2 is a short-hand method of writing group by 1st column selected and 2nd column selected.